# Loud Tick with Headset

Tags: audio, headphones

My phone (Samsung Galaxy S) has a loud "tick" on some actions (opening and closing applications or menus) It is fine when I don't have my headset on, but with earphones in it is unbearably high pitched.  Is there a way to control this noise so it it doesnt' happen when I've got my headphones on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android 2.1 Eclair, one can turn these clicks off by navigating to SETTINGS > SOUND & DISPLAY:

Scroll down to AUDIBLE TOUCH TONES & AUDIBLE SELECTION and uncheck both options.

Hopefully, there are similar options on your SGS.

Comment: It was under `Settings > Sound > Audible Selection` Thank you!